# Javascript destructuring data in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native and I am trying to pass data to child component, and after that I want to use map method for displaying user data with key value.
[image: Data converted to array]
So i get this data after making array from object, how should i destruct it to get username etc..
**PARENT COMPONENT:**

```
render() {
    let userMap = Object.entries(this.state.users).map(key => key);

    return (
      <ViewPager
        users={userMap}
        usersRetrieved={this.state.usersRetrieved}
        addNewMatch={this.addNewMatch}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
      />
    );
```

**CHILD COMPONENT:**

```
<Text>{JSON.stringify(props.users)}</Text>
```

How should i get username or profile_picture data?
I tried to do props.users[0].username but no luck

DATA EXAMPLE WITH 3 USERS:

```
{
  "lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": {
    "email": "emilissssss@temp.lt",
    "fbid": "3008*******71455",
    "gender": "male",
    "profile_picture": "...",
    "username": "Emilis"
  },
  "tempuser": {
    "email": "temp@temp.lt",
    "fbid": 315151515,
    "gender": "female",
    "matches": {
      "lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": [Object]
    },
    "profile_picture": "...",
    "username": "Egle"
  },
  "thirdUserID":{
    "email": "temp@temp.lt"
    "username": "thirdUserUsername"
    ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `let userMap = Object.entries(this.state.users).map(key => key);`? why not simply pass `let userMap = this.state.users`?

Comment: `props.users[0].map(...` ...but why is your data in an array in an array? Can you normalize it a little bit before your component is consuming it?

Comment: @palaѕн if I pass it like state i get object, for using .map() i need array

Comment: @DrewReese I think because of this: let userMap = Object.entries(this.state.users).map(key => key);

Comment: @DrewReese And there is two [] because it's only one user, there will be more users, so it closes single user data.

Comment: Can you please post `this.state.users` in the post so that I can better understand the issue. I am not able to get how are you storing multiple users in an object?

Comment: @palaѕн added my data object with 2 users now

Comment: Ok, could you please update it once to show where will the third user go and how will the object look after that.

Comment: @palaѕн added third user

Comment: @palaѕн I tried it works, but now how i get USERID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `userMap` variable in parent component like

```
let userMap = Object.entries(this.state.users).map(([key, value]) => value);
```

This returns an array of user objects like:

```
[{
    "email": "emilissssss@temp.lt",
    "fbid": "3008*******71455",
    "gender": "male",
    "profile_picture": "...",
    "username": "Emilis"
  },
  {
    "email": "temp@temp.lt",
    "fbid": 315151515,
    "gender": "female",
    "matches": {
      "lwcIQTcpAae4e38hrD2K5Ar76W93": [Object]
    },
    "profile_picture": "...",
    "username": "Egle"
  },
  {
    "email": "temp@temp.lt"
    "username": "thirdUserUsername"
      ...
  }
]
```

Then in child component you can simply `.map()` over all users like:

```
{props.users.map(user => (
  <Text>{user.username}</Text>
))}
```

Edit:

As, you need the userid also, then update `userMap` variable in parent component like:

```
let userMap = Object.entries(this.state.users);
```

Then in the child component, update `map` like:

```
{props.users.map(([key, user]) => (
  <Text>{key}</Text>
  <Text>{user.username}</Text>
))}
```

Or,

```
{props.users.map(([key, user]) => (
  <Text>{key + ', ' + user.username}</Text>
))}
```

Comment: Yes it works, i see that userID has disappeared. How I should take the userID?

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience. It works. I need more to read about object-array decomposition.

Comment: Yup, it is bit tricky at first, but everything in the world is difficult at first until it becomes easy, right? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing props.users[0][1].username instead? Since it seems to be the second value of an array inside an array

Comment: Hi, yes it works, how to make it with map? Because now there is only 1 user, but there will be more in this array

Comment: `props.users[0].map(...`

Comment: one more thing, in result i get username: "Egle" with this " is there a way to not display " ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following thing:

```js
{props.users.map(user => (
  <Text>{user[0].username}</Text>
))}
```

Comment: try `user[0].username`?

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon yes, you are right. The `user` is an array.

Comment: @MarcoCaldera still it does not display data, but like this: props.users[0][1].username I can get username. But i need to make it with map, because there will be more users.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with `Object.entries(this.state.users).map(key => key);` ? `Object.entries` already returns an array so there's no need to map it afterwards like that I reckon.

Anyway, to destructure an object in js:

```
const obj = {
  a: "value",
  b: "other value",
}
const {a,b} = obj
// a "value", b "other value"
```

Note that the variable and the key should be named the same.
And now you have a and b as constants available in your code.

In your child component you could have smth like this:

```
render() {
    let users = props.users

    return users.map(user => {
        const {username, email} = user; // destructure whatever you want
        return <Text>{email} {username}</Text> // display it the wy you want
    });
}
```

Comment: can you check my object data updated in the question?

Answer (score 0):

`Array` appears to be tied up several times.

The value you want is in the second index of the second array.

```js
{props.users.map(user => (
  <Text>{user[1].username}</Text>
))}
```